# How to pass dynamic values using MVC AJax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC and AJax.BeginForm to do some ajax updating of my page. The BeginForm code looks something like:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("HandleCrop", "Card", 
                   new 
                   { 
                       accept = true, 
                       id = Model.ImageUpload.ID, 
                       file = Model.ImageUpload.File, 
                       imageCropX = Model.CropInfo.X,
                       imageCropY = Model.CropInfo.Y,
                       imageCropWidth = Model.CropInfo.Width,
                       imageCropHeight = Model.CropInfo.Height                        
                   }, 
                   new AjaxOptions 
                   { 
                       HttpMethod = "POST", 
                       OnComplete = "ConfirmCompleted", 
                       OnSuccess = "ReloadUpload", 
                       OnFailure = "Failure" 
                   }, null))
```

The Model.CropInfo is being put in as hidden fields like so:

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CropInfo.X) %>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CropInfo.Y) %>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CropInfo.Width) %>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CropInfo.Height) %>
```

However, these values are being dynamically modified by some client side javascript, and these values need to be posted through the Ajax call back to the server. The above code will obviously not work as the imageCrop.. parameters in the Ajax form are being filled when the page is rendered (therefore being all 0).

My question is: what is the correct way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ajax this part should be absolutely removed:

```
    imageCropX = Model.CropInfo.X,
    imageCropY = Model.CropInfo.Y,
    imageCropWidth = Model.CropInfo.Width,
    imageCropHeight = Model.CropInfo.Height
```

With `TryUpdateModel` in the `Action` your `CropInfo` should be filled OK from posted data.

If you are **NOT USING** automatic update of the model (or via `TryUpdateModel`)
and instead of that you are **USING** this data as input parameters in `Action` then just rename these `Action` parameters to `CropInfo_X`, `CropInfo_Y`, `CropInfo_Width` and `CropInfo_Height` (I think this is how the hidden fields will be named in HTML, check this in page source)

Comment: I am not using automatic update of the model. I deleted the parameters as you described, and the hidden fields are indeed called the way you describe (with the _ ). However I still don't understand how these values will end up in the function 'HandleCrop'. Adding a Model argument to HandleCrop doesn´t work as this will just be an uninitialised object. Could you please elaborate how to do this correctly?

Comment: They will end up in action because when Ajax is making post request will find and serialize all input, hidden, select and other fields inside your form. All you need to do is to make sure that your parameter names in Action match the names of fields in HTML. This behavior is already implemented and occurs behind the scenes.

Comment: I have seen now that Names of your hidden fields would contain . (dot) which is not good for this scenario as C# does not allow dot in identifiers. If previously discussed does not work, replace your Html.HiddenFor with something like <input type="hidden" ...

Comment: THe ID's are with _ as you said before, not with dots (.). I've added the hidden field names as arguments to the action function now, but all parameters are being passed in as null

Comment: Just make the Name of hidden field and Name of parameter in action be the same by any means needed and it will work.